# Intuitive explanation of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

An integral gives the area of the curve between $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis over some domain. Why is the lower bound of this area the $x$-axis? I've always accepted this at face value, and I know the pictorial explanation, but I don't see why it works in the integration itself, in which we explicitly state the function, the two boundaries for $x$, but not the lower horizontal boundary i.e. the $x$-axis. I hope this question makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: it is because you are adding up values of y dx when you integrate, and y is measured from the x-axis

Comment: Note that $f(x)$ is itself the (signed) distance between the $x$-axis and the point on the graph $(x,f(x))$, so the $x$-axis is already 'built in'.

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is the continuously varying velocity  at time $x$ of a car travelling in a straight line. The distance from the car's position at time $A$ to its position at time $B $ (with $B>A$) is $\int_A^Bf(x)dx$. Regardless of whether or not $f$ can take both positive and negative values.

Answer (score 2):

For any given value of $x$, e.g. $x_0$, the value $f(x_0)$ is equal to the length between the $x$-axis point $(x_0,0)$ and the curve point $(x_0, f(x_0))$. So, $f(x) dx$ is the area of an infinitesimal rectangle between the $x$-axis and the curve.